# AJAX performs its function, but the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

My django web application has a form to add an item to the cart. I wrote ajax code so that when adding a product, the page is not refreshed. It turns out that the **product adds to the cart** but the page with the json-response opens *{"success": true}*.

I see that in views.py 'product_id' is written twice but I don't know which is better.

**views.py**

```
def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        quantity = 1
        user = request.user

        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(product_id=product_id, quantity=quantity, user=user)
        cart_item.save()

        data = {'success': True}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data = {'success': False, 'error': 'error'}
        return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
```

**urls.py**
`path('add_to_cart/<int:product_id>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),`

**product_detail.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'add_to_cart' single_product.id %}" method="POST" id="add-to-cart-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ single_product.id }}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add-to-cart-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
     
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Nothing is written in the console.

**JQuery** is working, I checked this script.

```
<script src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.6.4.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('jQuery is working!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you don't want the page to refresh on you? (if I understood correctly), have you tried removing the `type="submit"` from your button?

Comment: I just removed 'type="submit' and it still refreshes

Comment: it's probably becuz it's on a form with `action="url...`

Comment: I removed the action and now the page is not refreshing but also it doesnt add product in cart

Comment: remove action and set url in js directly

Comment: How to set url directly?

Comment: preventDefault should be doing it.... So if nothing is written to the console, seems like your function is not being bound to the submit event.

Comment: I removed action, set url: "{% url 'add_to_cart' %}", its not refreshing and not adding in cart, nothing in console

Comment: did you change this function? `$('#add-to-cart-form').on('submit', function(event) {` if you removed your `type="submit"` from your button then this function also has to be adjusted

Comment: How to change it?

Comment: you could change `'submit'` for a `'click'` event, also change this `var url = $(this).attr('action');` since you removed the action

Comment: `var data = $(this).serialize();` that might also change

Comment: When the url is $(this).attr('action') and the event is 'click' it answers with page {"success": true}. When the url is "{% url 'add_to_cart' %}" it doesn't work at all so maybe I write the direct url wrong

Comment: good, make a few more tests and see if it works then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your code locally and it worked exactly as you expect it to, in that the ajax reached the callback and the form did not submit itself.

Perhaps try this. It's not an answer but might uncover something. I'm assuming you're using Chrome debugger.

- Inspect the source. Does the form look like you expect or is it malformed?
- Enable preserve log on Chrome debugger, breakpoint at the handler's preventdefault, and in the ajax callback and error handler, then click your Add button and step through.

Comment: I don't know why it worked but I bypassed cache with ctrl+F5 and now it works. Thank you for the idea that the problem is not about code